# Re-run failed tests in testNG

Tags: java, testng

Is there any way to re-run failed tests using TestNG when same set of tests are run in different threads?  I see there people use Retry listeners [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320794/2020491 ] as in this link. But this does not seem to be working when i run same set of tests in multiple threads.

Below is my `testng.xml` where in `com.example.SampleTest` i have 2 tests in which 1 fails. i get the below result when run

`===============================================
SampleTest
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Skips: 1
===============================================`

The one with test `name="ONE"`, failed test runs for the second time but failed test is not run the second time for test with `name="TWO"` (when the class names are different for both the tests then this works as expected)

```
<suite name="SampleTest" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="1"><test name="ONE">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.example.SampleTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="TWO">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.example.SampleTest" />
    </classes>
</test>

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.example.TestListener"/>
    <listener class-name="com.example.RetryListener"/>
</listeners> </suite>
```

Below is my class file

```
@Test
public void testOne(){
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}

@Test
public void testTwo(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

Comment: As you are using the same class in 2 tests, I suppose the retry analyzer has some problems to determine the good test method. You should open an issue on github.com/cbeust/testng/issues with a full runnable sample.

Comment: @JulienHerr Issue is created with github [https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1241 ]