# Filtering automatically re-run tests from a report

Tags: testng, allure

I have an automated test suite built using TestNG and want to add automatic retries to eliminate some flakyness (I know hiding errors might lead to problems down the road, this is mostly just a proof of concept at this point) but I'm having issues not getting the re-runs to show in the finalized Allure report.

Basically I followed the steps in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208202/retry-failed-test-case-in-testng) and it works but the last part, about adding the second listener to filter out the results either doesn't work the way I implemented it or doesn't work when a given test fails every retry.

I have the 3 classes detailed in the answer linked above:

```
public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {} 
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {}
public class TestListener implements ITestListener {}
```

And all the listeners I have in the `testng-run.xml` look like this:

```
<listeners>
       <listener class-name="com.org.qa.automation.transformers.FrameworkTransformer"></listener>
       <listener class-name="com.org.qa.automation.suite.utils.RetryListener"></listener>
       <listener class-name="com.org.qa.automation.suite.utils.TestListener"></listener>
</listeners>
```

I'm setting the max retry counter to 2.

What happens when I run the full suite is that if a test fails it retries up to twice more (it runs 3 times at most) then if it fails every time it fails.

The problem I'm having is that in that case the end report will show the same test ran 3 times and the total test cases ran would take those retries into account screwing up the coverage %.

How can I go around filtering the results so that if a give tests fails every time it only appears once in the resulting Allure report?. 
Note: I also need skipped and broken tests to show up in the report as well.

Comment: I just added support for test reties, we gonna release Allure 2 beta 7 in few days, and then I will add an answer with more details

Answer (score 1):

Allure handles test retries since [BETA8](https://bintray.com/qameta/generic/allure2/2.0-BETA8). Simply generate the report from the results and all the retried tests will be hidden from the report statistics and displayed in reties section at test case page.

Comment: That's awesome!. Quick question... and probably a noob one. Is it available as a Maven dependency to add to our POM?. I can't find it in the maven repo.

Comment: If you mean maven plugin to generate the report - it is not available yet.